# Parabolic cylinder function as the solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation
$\frac {d^2f} {dz^2} + \left( az^2 +bz +c \right)f = 0$. I found out what with  completing the square and rescaling the variable I can get equation like $\frac {d^2f} {dz^2} + \left( \nu + \frac {1}{2} - \frac {z^2}{4}\right)f = 0$. Then with setting the $\nu$ parameter I can get solution in terms of Hermit functions.
But for me it is not obviously which exactly transformation are needed for this? What should I do to get the second equation from the first?
Thank you.